# Finding latest value in the list of numbers using lists, and slice syntax

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, syntax

I need help with this assignment. I could only do as far as my code below and I am really struggling with the rest of the requirements (below).

***Requirements***

- Make a list of ten integers named nums in no order. 
  Use numbers less than 100.
- Use a loop to display the list with all numbers on the same line separated by spaces.
- Use slice syntax to make a new list named nums2 from the middle six numbers in nums.
- Pass nums2 as the sole argument to a void function named list_func.
- Inside the list_func function, display the the largest number in the slice and its index.

Sample output is:

```
Here is the original list:
22 12 55 44 85 64 33 19 96 70 
Largest value in slice is 85
85 is at index 2 in the slice
```

Script is:

```
import random

def main():

    nums =[]
    num2 = []

    for n in range (10):
        rando = random.randint(1,100)
        nums.append(rando)

    print('Here is the original list ')
    print(nums)


main()
```

I am on the nums2 list part.

Comment: For your specific values: `nums2 = nums[2:-2]`

Answer (score 1):

> - use slice syntax to make a new list named nums2 from the middle six numbers in nums.

```
MIDDLE_N = 6

n = (len(nums) - MIDDLE_N) // 2
nums2 = nums[n:][:MIDDLE_N]

print('Here is the middle 6 list ')
print(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums2))
```

`nums[n:]` makes a new list starting at index `n`. `nums[n:][:MIDDLE_N]` makes a new list from `nums[n:]` with the first `MIDDLE_N` elements.

> - Pass nums2 as the sole argument to a void function named list_func.
> - Inside the list_func function, display the the largest number in the slice and its index.

```
def list_func(l):
    top = max(l)
    print('Largest value in slice is {}'.format(top))
    print('{} is at index {} in the slice'.format(top, l.index(top)))

list_func(nums2)
```

### Putting it all together

```
import random

def list_func(l):
    top = max(l)
    print('Largest value in slice is {}'.format(top))
    print('{} is at index {} in the slice'.format(top, l.index(top)))

def main():
    nums = []
    for n in range (10):
        rando = random.randint(1,100)
        nums.append(rando)

    print('Here is the original list ')
    # This is a kind of loop -- a generator expression.
    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums))

    MIDDLE_N = 6

    n = (len(nums) - MIDDLE_N) // 2
    nums2 = nums[n:][:MIDDLE_N]

    print('Here is the middle 6 list ')
    print(' '.join(str(n) for n in nums2))

    list_func(nums2)

main()
```

### Output

```
Here is the original list 
49 82 16 68 47 8 30 41 24 34
Here is the middle 6 list 
16 68 47 8 30 41
Largest value in slice is 68
68 is at index 1 in the slice
```